# In a Firefox WebExtension, how can I safely access value properties of a page-script's JS object?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

In my extension, I need to access some data stored by page JavaScript. 
However, I also need to make sure the page cannot trick my extension into running arbitrary code. The data I need should be stored in plain old value properties (if I understand what they are) on a JS object bound to the page's window, but just in case, I want to be sure not to call any malicious code if it's present.

Is there a way to safely access this data from a content script, treating the JS object (and its children) as a simple dictionary?

I've found two pages that might offer some help:

- [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Accessing_page_script_objects_from_content_scripts) page describes a method of getting a reference to the page's `window` object, but it is unsafe to do so.
- [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Xray_vision#Xray_semantics_for_Object_and_Array) page appears to show that Xray vision provides safe access to the value properties of an object, but does not seem to explain how to get Xray vision for a page-script object, at least from a content-script rather than actual chrome code.

Is there some way to combine these two to allow safe access to the data?

Comment: This seems too broad without specifying what the data is and how you use it.

Comment: For writing an answer, it would be helpful to have specific examples of the information you are trying to access. You are correct that accessing data through `wrappedJSObject` has security issues and should generally be avoided. It's also not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Indeed, a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve would help to explain the security implications.

Comment: @the8472 I'm not sure what I should say about it in the post. It's... a key of a dictionary (on the window object), itself an array of dictionaries. There should be no functions or anything in it and all the objects should have been created just as simple value properties. But, I also don't want the extension to be vulnerable if it's messed with in some way.

Comment: just write initialize an example object and which property you would like to access and what types they are exactly. as a code sample.